# adding reference to facebook sdk in android

Tags: android, facebook

I am making an android app in which i am using facebook login.
I am unable to add the facebook sdk as library to my project.
can anyone tell what could be the problem.
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Facebook SDK configuration on Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945618/android-facebook-sdk-configuration-on-eclipse) , just check the answer provided by Mr. Robby Pond

Comment: from linked answer: "make sure to extract it into a folder that is not within the eclipse workspace." Seems to be a glitch quite easy to oversee at least that's what brought me here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got facebook sdk from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk Link.

Import this project in your eclips.

then go to package explorer of your eclipse and right click your original project --> property --> android . at this place below built target there is library option add your facebook project from here.
It may help you.

Comment: i have already done this but problem is that i am unable to add that as library to another project

Comment: i think you are in need of this link http://www.radiantsilverlabs.com/content/using-facebook-api-android-windows-starters-guide

Comment: i think you got wrong facebook sdk which may include other program please check above given link you got every thing

Comment: can you explain little bit what you want to do exactly ,In your question comment by PM send you one link please refer it..

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve your problem?                                                                  If not here is what I did. In Eclipse right click in your app folder select Build Path -> Link Source and finally find the facebook-sdk folder click Finish and you are done.