# Android Facebook Login Failing

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I'm having some troubles with implementing Facebook log in into my Android App.

I have followed three different tutorials to a T (or so I thought I guess).

Here are some links to the tutorials I have followed:
I've followed this video as well as the setup: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

I've followed this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/

And this one:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/

Unfortunately I either get a stage where when I try to log in nothing happens.  It asks for the authentication and then doesn't log in.
Or I get a FATAL EXCEPTION:
[image: Fatal Exception]

These are the libraries I have:
[image: Libraries]

I have TestApp/src, TestApp/gen, Android 4.2.2, Android Private Dependencies and Android Private Libraries under Order and Export.

Finally under Project -> Properties -> Android I have Android 4.2.2 under Build Target and the FacebookSDK under Library.

```
package com.test.TestApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    // Start Facebook Login
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // Calls whenever it changes state.
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                            welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                        }
                        
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Kind of stuck at this point with the Facebook implementation.

If any more information is needed please just ask.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964816/unable-to-configure-facebook-sdk-in-eclipse/17349410#17349410) answer I posted. I think it might solve your issue

Comment: MY GOD YOU'RE A GENIUS! I thought I had tried EVERYTHING! For whatever reason it never occurred to me that it could be an issue with what was being imported from the FacebookSDK project as we're using it.  Appreciate the help! It finally works.

When I clean the projects though there is an error in the console saying: Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list, but not all versions are identical...

Any clue how to fix it?

Comment: No problem. Yes, so basically what is happening is that the facebook-sdk comes with a version of the android-support-v4.jar that is probably not the same as the one that eclipse used when it created your project. All you need to do is to copy the version on your libs directory to the libs directory inside the facebook sdk library