# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.R$layout while clicking on fb login button

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am using the Facebook SDK to implement Facebook login in Android. I've added FB SDK as a library and compiled it, which worked quite smoothly.

But when I exported the apk as a signed APK, and then installed the apk and started it, I got this NoClassDefError everytime I clicked on FB and thus I'm a bit clueless as to why this is happening. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I wrote this answer on how to properly configure Facebook's SDK a while back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964816/unable-to-configure-facebook-sdk-in-eclipse/17349410#17349410