# Invalid ZIP archive: facebook.jar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook

I really need help with this error:

> Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
>       Please check logcat output for more details :

```
Invalid ZIP archive: C:\Users\POSTE5\Desktop\facebook\bin\facebook.jar
    An internal error occurred during: "Refreshing external folders":
   {java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.getChild(LocalFile.java:179)
at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.childStores(FileStore.java:127)
at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.childInfos(FileStore.java:106)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.UnifiedTree.getLocalList(UnifiedTree.java:347)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.UnifiedTree.addChildren(UnifiedTree.java:139)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.UnifiedTree.addNodeChildrenToQueue(UnifiedTree.java:245)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.UnifiedTree.accept(UnifiedTree.java:111)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.refreshResource(FileSystemResourceManager.java:920)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.refresh(FileSystemResourceManager.java:904)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.refreshLocal(Resource.java:1663)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ExternalFoldersManager$RefreshJob.run(ExternalFoldersManager.java:440)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

}

An internal error occurred during: "Searching for markers".

Comment: what do you need help with? Please improve your question.

Comment: i was developping an app android everthing works perfect but when i changed my environment to another question i got this error when i compile the app; there is no error on the file of the application but in the compilation

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMS**

1. Your ZIP archive is invalid
2. Your Garbage Collector can't handle the "Refreshing external folders" action

**SOLLUTIONS**

1. Get a valid `facebook.jar` archive

If you already have a valid one **INSTALL IT** propperly!

- [Installing in Android Studio (IntelliJ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466921/android-studio-0-8-1-how-to-use-facebook-sdk)
- [Installing in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945618/android-facebook-sdk-configuration-on-eclipse)

  > Step1: Download Facebook Android SDK from github. 
  >   Step2: Extract it. (at any location). 
  >   Step3: In Eclipse create new project using create project from existing source option 
  >   Step4: Enter the project name as "com_facebook_android". 
  >   Step5: Set Location to "facebook" folder in extracted location. 
  >   Step6: Click Finish. 
  >   Step7: Select the "com_facebook_android" project in project explorer and right click select export option. 
  >   Step8: In the export wizard select JAR file in Java folder. 
  >   Step9: Click next then browse the location for jar file and give the name as yor wish like "facebook-android.jar" 
  >   Step10: Click finish........ JAR file will be created in that location

Comment: do you have any link to this sdk